# Can i create a formula field to calculate the time in business hours between Case created date to now/Closed date?

Tags: formula, calendar

Can i create a formula field to calculate the time in business hours between Case created date to now/Closed date?   I'm looking for a non code solution which is equivalent to finding the difference in date/time using apex with the BusinessHours.diff() method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this can't be done without code.  There is no formula that accesses the business hours settings.  Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

You could try this answer which calculates the time difference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126378/salesforce-formula-calculate-business-hours-between-two-dates/11129346 but you would have to make assumptions about the business hours and the formula wouldn't mirror exactly to them. Hopefully close enough